# How to search without order in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a rock-paper-scissors game.
I was at the step of making a function to check who won.
But I didn't want to make tons of `if-else` statements. I was thinking about some logic to reduce those.

I have come up with the following implementation

```
moves_dict = {('R', 'P'): 'P',
              ('R', 'S'): 'R',
              ('S', 'P'): 'S'}

user_comp = ['User', 'Computer']

# item_check = (userMove, computerMove)
move_check = ('R', 'S')

if moves_dict.get(move_check):
    print('Move exists')
    print(
        f"Winner : {user_comp[move_check.index(moves_dict.get(move_check))]}")

elif moves_dict.get(move_check[::-1]):
    print("Rev move exist")
    print(
        f"Winner : {user_comp[move_check.index(moves_dict.get(move_check[::-1]))]}")

else:
    print('Tie')
```

I am first eliminating the possibility of a Tie, then moving on to get the value(`winner move`) and then looking up its index in the key. After getting index I am just printing the winner from the `user_comp`.

As you can see the key-value pairs basically are `move:winner move`. I agree the code is going bit towards unreadable state but

I wanted to know if there is way I don't have to use the `elif` statement.

I want to deploy this in a computer vision project on webcam feed so speed is also of importance.

Comment: Add three more entries with the tuples reversed and the winners reversed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a little modulo:

```
>>> for user in 'RPS':
        for computer in 'RPS':
            winner = ('RPS'.find(user) - 'RPS'.find(computer)) % 3
            print(f'{user=} {computer=} =>',
                  ('Tie', 'User wins', 'Computer wins')[winner])

user='R' computer='R' => Tie
user='R' computer='P' => Computer wins
user='R' computer='S' => User wins
user='P' computer='R' => User wins
user='P' computer='P' => Tie
user='P' computer='S' => Computer wins
user='S' computer='R' => Computer wins
user='S' computer='P' => User wins
user='S' computer='S' => Tie
```

To answer your title question about searching without order in a dictionary, you could use `frozenset` keys instead of tuples:

```
>>> moves_dict = {frozenset('RP'): 'P',
                  frozenset('RS'): 'R',
                  frozenset('SP'): 'S'}
>>> for user in 'RPS':
        for computer in 'RPS':
            winner = moves_dict.get(frozenset((user, computer)))
            print(f'{user=} {computer=} =>', winner)

user='R' computer='R' => None
user='R' computer='P' => P
user='R' computer='S' => R
user='P' computer='R' => P
user='P' computer='P' => None
user='P' computer='S' => S
user='S' computer='R' => R
user='S' computer='P' => S
user='S' computer='S' => None
```

(Though this only shows the winning hand, not who won... don't really want to extend that, as I'd go with my first solution anyway.)

Comment: This is really amazing. I never really paid much attention to modulo. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a great solution to OP's problem -- it shows a better way of achieving the same result. However, it doesn't answer the question, so others who find this question in the future might not find the answer helpful. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251848/843953

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Hmm, but did you notice that that's **not** the top-voted answer there, and that the top-voted answer there says the opposite? :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm not complaining about your answer being accepted. Because SO isn't just meant to be a forum to answer the asker's questions -- it's supposed to help others who might have the same question and find this question by searching the web -- so it's better to answer the question _and_ suggest a better way instead of just suggesting a better way. That way you help out OP, educate them, and answer others who might not have the exact same problem as OP but still have the same question. FWIW, I upvoted your answer a couple minutes after you posted it because it's so elegant

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Alright alright... I added a dict solution :-)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Ugh, actually that just shows the winning hand, not the winner. Not sure I wanna finish that or just delete it again...

Comment: eh, it answer's OP's question about tuple dict keys not caring about order. Part of being a programmer is adapting generalized solutions to your specific case. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah, pretty much added that as an excuse now :-)

Comment: @superbrain thank you for the updated answer. I've learnt a lot from this discussion

Answer (score 1):

You could put all of the options in the dictionary so a single `get` is definitive.

```
# total outcomes for game
winner_ops = ["user", "computer", "draw", "invalid"]

# winning moves indexed by (user, computer) selection
moves_dict = {('R', 'P'): 1,
              ('R', 'S'): 0,
              ('S', 'P'): 1}

# reversse the moves for opposite win
moves_dict.update((tuple(reversed(key)), int(not moves_dict[key]))      
    for key in list(moves_dict.keys()))

# add draws
moves_dict.update(((val, val), 2) for val in "PRS")

# test
move_check = ('R', 'S')
winner = moves_dict.get(move_check, 3)
print(winner_ops[winner])
```